# Prepending some text to each "wildcard" argument in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard, wildcard-expansion

A simple Example: `mybin *.txt` will expand to `mybin a.txt b.txt c.txt`

But I'm looking for a simple solution to have an expansion to something like: `mybin --conf a.txt --conf b.txt --conf c.txt`.

Is there a built in to do this? What is the simplest way for this?

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way to do so, but if you need more than a conf I would follow the lead of the OS... For example, `apt` has its `apt.conf.d` folder, as many other programs

Comment: `sed 's/\(^.*$\)/--conf \1/g' < <(ls -1 *.txt)` (where that is `ls -one`...) You can simply remove the new lines with a `printf "%s "`, e.g. `printf "%s " $(sed 's/\(^.*$\)/--conf \1/g' < <(ls -1 *.txt))`

Comment: Is `mybin` capable of reading configs from `stdin` ?

Comment: If so, I think you can do sth like this `cat *.txt | mybin --conf -`, which is a more secure way to do this than using `eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is my friend:

```
mybin $(find /wherever/ -name '*.txt' -printf '--conf %p ')
```

Comment: if filenames contain spaces or special characters ... `eval mybin "$(find ./ -name '*.txt' -printf '--conf "%p" ')"`

Comment: Dangerous: If a file is named `$( rm -rf / )`, that code will be executed.
Also, with Feng's modification, `"` in filenames will fail (analogously if you used `'`).
`printf %q` is how you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky solution:

```
eval mybin "--conf\ {`echo *.txt|tr -s " " ,`}"
```

Answer (score 0):

for all txt files

```
eval mybin "$(printf -- '--conf %q ' *.txt)"
```

If only for certain txt files

```
eval mybin '--conf "'{a,b,c}.txt'"'
```

Maybe we should use a wrapper function. This is not a builtin solution, but it works well than the previous two commands if filenames contain spaces or special characters.

function `mybinw`:

```
function mybinw() {
  declare -a mybin_opts

  for file in "$@"; do
    mybin_opts+=(--conf "$file")
  done

  mybin "${mybin_opts[@]}"
}
```

Test:

`mybin`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for q in "$@"; do
  echo "=> $q"
done
```

Create some txt files, some file names include spaces or special characters

```
touch {a,b,c,d,efg,"h h"}.txt 'a(1).txt' 'b;b.txt'
```

For all txt files:

```
eval mybin "$(printf -- '--conf %q ' *.txt)"
```

> ```
> => --conf
> => a(1).txt
> => --conf
> => a.txt
> => --conf
> => b;b.txt
> => --conf
> => b.txt
> => --conf
> => c.txt
> => --conf
> => d.txt
> => --conf
> => efg.txt
> => --conf
> => h h.txt
> ```

for certain txt files:

```
eval mybin '--conf "'{a,b,c,"h h"}.txt'"'
```

> ```
> => --conf
> => a.txt
> => --conf
> => b.txt
> => --conf
> => c.txt
> => --conf
> => h h.txt
> ```

Using a wrapper function

```
touch 'c"c.txt'

mybinw *.txt
```

> ```
> => --conf
> => a(1).txt
> => --conf
> => a"b.txt
> => --conf
> => a.txt
> => --conf
> => b;b.txt
> => --conf
> => b.txt
> => --conf
> => c"c.txt
> => --conf
> => c.txt
> => --conf
> => d.txt
> => --conf
> => efg.txt
> => --conf
> => h h.txt
> ```

Comment: try it also with  `'a"b.txt'`

Comment: @mosvy Ah, yes. actually, this question doesn't have a perfect answer.

Comment: Regarding the `eval` solution, you could utilize `%q` to protect the special characters: `eval "mybin$(printf ' --conf %q' *.txt)"`.

Comment: @PesaThe Thank you very much! I updated my answer with your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
# usage mix command switch args ...
mix(){
        p=$1; shift; q=$1; shift; c=
        i=1; for a; do c="$c $q \"\${$i}\""; i=$((i+1)); done
        eval "$p $c"
}

mix mybin --conf *.txt
```

This is portable to any POSIX shell, not just `bash`, and is able to handle filenames with spaces, special characters, etc:

```
$ qecho(){ for a; do echo "{$a}"; done; }
$ touch 'a;b' "a'b" "a\\'b" 'a"b' 'a\"b' '(a b)' '(a    b)' 'a
b'
$ mix qecho --conf *
{--conf}
{(a    b)}
{--conf}
{(a b)}
{--conf}
{a
b}
{--conf}
{a"b}
{--conf}
{a'b}
{--conf}
{a;b}
{--conf}
{a\"b}
{--conf}
{a\'b}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- *.txt

for thing do
    shift
    set -- "$@" --conf "$thing"
done

mybin "$@"
```

This would use the list of positional parameters (`$@`) to hold the expanded glob pattern.  We then loop over these items and modify `$@` by inserting `--conf` before each.  The `mybin` utility can then be invoked with this list.

The quoting in the code is deliberate to stop the shell from splitting any strings on whitespaces and from expanding any filename globs if they occur as proper parts of the filenames that `*.txt` matches.

A `bash`-specific variation:

```
files=( *.txt )

for thing in "${files[@]}"; do
    args+=( --conf "$thing" )
done

mybin "${args[@]}"
```

---

Shorter variations of both of the above.  First for `/bin/sh`:

```
set --
for thing in *.txt; do
    set -- "$@" --conf "$thing"
done

mybin "$@"
```

Then for `bash`:

```
for thing in *.txt; do
    args+=( --conf "$thing" )
done

mybin "${args[@]}"
```

---

As a shell function:

```
delim_run () {
    cmd=$1
    delim=$2

    shift 2

    for thing do
        shift
        set -- "$@" "$delim" "$thing"
    done

    "$cmd" "$@"
}
```

You would then be able to do

```
delim_run mybin --conf *.txt
```